# If (value === true) not working

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain to me why this is not working? The value is true, it is boolean and if I check it like I usually do if(value) {}; it works. Why not like this?

```
function updateRecords(value) {

  console.log(!!(value));        // true
  console.log(typeof(!!(value)));    //boolean

    if (value === true) {
        alert("success");
      }
 }

    updateRecords("Take a Chance on Me");
```

Comment: It is not a boolean.  The "thing" you were running `typeof` against *was* a boolean, due to type casting.  To prove it, try logging "typeof(value)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value that you are working with is a string, not a Boolean. When you wrote this:

```
console.log(!!(value));
```

You were converting the string value to a Boolean, but you weren't capturing it. You converted it and logged it and then it got thrown away. Then your next line:

```
console.log(typeof(value));  // string NOT Boolean
```

went back to testing the original value of `value` (a string).

The triple equal sign checks for "type and value equality", so your `if` test fails.

Now, if you remove one of the equal signs (`==`) and test for simple "value equality with type conversion", it still won't work unless the text you are testing against converts to the same number that `true` will (see link below for details), but that won't happen, **your string will convert to `NaN` (not a number) and `true` will convert to `1`, so even `value == true` will fail**.

You can see more details about how equality and type conversion work together **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)**.

At any rate, in this case don't test against the Boolean `true`, just test for the existence of data: `if(value)` which doesn't attempt to convert your value to a `number`, it attempts to convert it to a Boolean. As long as you don't have a string that contains ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values (ie. `""`, `"0"`, `"false"`, `"  "`), it will convert to `true`

```js
function updateRecords(value) {

  console.log(!!value);        // true
  console.log(typeof value);    // string

    // Don't test against true (that's implied), just test the data.
    if (value) {
        alert("success");
    }
 }

updateRecords("Take a Chance on Me");
```

Or, capture the casted version of your data and then you can use `===`

```js
function updateRecords(value) {
  // Convert the value of "value" to a Boolean and
  // store that value back in the original variable
  value = !!value;

  // Now, let's test value AFTER capturing its converted value
  console.log(value);            // true
  console.log(typeof value);    // boolean

    if (value === true) {
        alert("success");
      }
 }

updateRecords("Take a Chance on Me");
```

Comment: You forgot the `===`!

Comment: Got it! ;) Ha-ha!

Comment: I thought about comparing it with double equals  bit it still didn't work. Can you explain why is that? I was under impression that since !!("Take a Chance on me") is true and the string is truthy that it will wotk if I compare it with boolean value.

Comment: @Igor-Vuk Yes, the last thing works. As I said it in my answer, you are not changing the value but you are comparing it with `===`.

Comment: @Igor-Vuk It doesn't work with `==` because the values are first converted to numbers, not Booleans and then compared.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not yet typecasting in the second instance.

```
if (!!(value) === true) {
    alert("success");
}
```

Previously you were checking:

```
"Take a Chance on Me" === true      // This obviously returns false.
```

The above should work. Else you shouldn't use the `===` operator. You should use `==`:

```
if (value == true) {
    alert("success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS can be surprising (@praveenkumar alias flashgordon : not always obvious) :

```
""   == false is true
"1"  == false is false (ok so far)
"0"  == false is true  (looks weird)
" "  == false is true  (wtf...)
"\n" == false is true  (wtf²)
```

Comment: That's good information, but a not very good answer to the question.